# How to disable auto fsck in Centos 7?

Tags: linux, centos7, fsck, rhel7

Is there a way to disable auto fsck while booting up on Centos 7 when it is XFS file system running on it.

I know in legacy versions, we use `touch /forcefsck`, `tune2fs -c0 -i0 /dev/FILESXX` etc to disable fsck on boot/reboot. Any idea about how it to be done in systemd/xfs system?.

Comment: In a harsh way you could symlink `/sbin/xfs_check`, `/sbin/fsck.xfs` or whatever is used to `/bin/true`.

Answer (score 1):

You could set the fsck field in `/etc/fstab` to `0` for the mount(s) you don't want to fsck at boot.  You set that in the sixth field of an `/etc/fstab` entry.

`/dev/mapper/centos-root   /                       xfs     defaults        0 0`

Reference [`man fstab`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/fstab.5.html).

Comment: @MikeA: heroically editing this answer is nice, but it would be fine to make your own answer too.